# CSV Document not reading properly

Tags: csv, netlogo

Im trying to add variables to my turtles based on an Excel document. The excel document is just two columns with 19 random numbers. It is saved as a CSV. Im getting an error that says : Expected a literal value. (line number 19, character 2)
error while turtle 17 running FILE-READ

However, all values are numbers in the document. This is the code

```
extensions [csv] 
globals [ turtle-data ]
 turtles-own [ awareness income housingtype adopt ]
 to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-turtles 20
  ask turtles [
   set color white
  ]
  ask turtles [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
; load-turtle-data
   ; setup-turtles
  load-data
 end

to load-data
  file-open "Ejemplocsv.csv"
  while [not file-at-end?] [
   ask turtles [
      set income file-read
      set housingtype file-read
      set size 1.5]
    ask turtles [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]]
  
  file-close
  show "file read"

end
```

I also tried instead a code that another user posted here but got the same error. This part replaces the load-data. It doesn't work either.

```
to load-turtle-data
 ifelse ( file-exists? "Ejemplocsv.csv" ) [
   set turtle-data []
   file-open "Ejemplocsv.csv"
   while [ not file-at-end? ][
      set turtle-data sentence turtle-data (list (list file-read file-read))
   ]
  user-message "File loading complete!"
  file-close
  ]
  [
     user-message "There is no input-data.txt file in current directory!" 
  ]
end

to setup-turtles
 foreach turtle-data [ iter ->
   crt 1 [
     set income item 0 iter
     set housingtype item 1 iter
   ]
 ]
end
```

I just want to know the most effective way to load csv data, or excel, to the variable of my turtles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that your csv file is indeed comma delimited, not space delimited.  `file-read` expects constants to be separated by white space and commas do not count as white space.  If you saved your Excel file with spaces as the delimiter, or if you used a text editor to change the commas to spaces in your csv file, your code should work.
But, if you are going to load the `csv extension`, you might as well use it.  The following code uses one command to read the whole csv file into `turtle-data`, as a list of lists, and `setup-turtles` then creates the turtles and uses `turtle-data` to populate their `income` and `housingtype` values. `csv:from-file` is perfectly happy with commas.  (Note you don't need `file-open` or `file-close` with `csv:from-file` as it does the opening and closing for you.)

```
extensions [csv]
globals [ turtle-data ]
turtles-own [ awareness income housingtype adopt ]

to load-turtle-data
  ifelse ( file-exists? "Ejemplocsv.csv" ) [
;    file-open "Ejemplocsv.csv"
    set turtle-data csv:from-file "Ejemplocsv.csv"
    user-message "File loading complete!"
;    file-close
  ]
  [
    user-message "There is no input-data.txt file in current directory!"
  ]
end

to setup-turtles
  foreach turtle-data [ iter ->
    crt 1 [
      set income item 0 iter
      set housingtype item 1 iter
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Charles! thanks for the correction. The good news is that i got another error. Can't find element 1 of the list [3;25], which is only of length 1.
error while turtle 18 running ITEM   Dont really know what it is, i thought that there were more turtles than data but thats not the case.

Comment: Is that a semicolon between the 3 and the 25?  And are you using commas or periods as the decimal separator?

Comment: It might be useful to post your csv file.

Comment: If you are really using the semicolon as your delimiter, which is not standard, you can tell csv:from-file to recognize it as such.  See https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html#csv:from-file